# Where is the used disk space if it is not in root

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, disk-space

I recently discovered that I only had a very small amount of disk space left. I found that my logs were getting quite huge so I reconfigured logrotate. However, I still have some issues.
Using `df -h` I can see that I have used 13 GB and have 6 GB left.

```
root@host01:/# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                      20G   13G  6.3G  67% /
udev                        10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                       50M  156K   50M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT   20G   13G  6.3G  67% /
tmpfs                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      100M     0  100M   0% /run/shm
```

However, if I go to the root `/` and do `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h` it shows that roughly 6 GB is used.

```
root@host01:/# du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h
du: cannot access `./proc/8902/task/8902/fd/5': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/8902/task/8902/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/8902/fd/5': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/8902/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
0   ./dev
0   ./proc
0   ./sys
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./mnt
4.0K    ./opt
4.0K    ./selinux
8.0K    ./tmp
12K ./srv
16K ./lost+found
104K    ./root
156K    ./run
5.9M    ./sbin
6.9M    ./bin
8.2M    ./etc
15M ./boot
121M    ./lib
332M    ./var
851M    ./usr
5.0G    ./home
6.3G    .
```

It seems odd that I should have used 13 GB and the total usage of the root shows 6,3 GB which seems a bit more reasonable. Does anyone know where the other 7 GB might be located and if I can restore any of it?

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16789805/720999).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely unlinked files that are still held open by one or more programs. One sure way to clear this space -- reboot.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! Do you know what is the best way to avoid this? Is it simply rebooting the system once in a while? Maybe with a cronjob to do it every night.

Comment: @SimonBS: Rather than deleting log files and the like, rotate them properly.

Comment: @SimonBS, look for the `logrotate` package.

Comment: Okay. I think it is setup correctly then. I configured logrotate to only store logs for a few days and then I deleted all previous logs. That's probably what caused problems. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonBS You shouldn't need to do anything as drastic as rebooting; you just need to restart the process responsible.  I have written a complete explanation in my blog: http://linuxtech.ie/wordpress/2012/10/31/missing-disk-space-linux-unix/